# Facebook Like to Unlock not working on first click

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using following code to unlock the coupon code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
      FB.init({
      appId: '4##############',
      xfbml: true,
      status: true,
      cookie: true,
      version: 'v2.11'
     });

    window.FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (response) {
        jQuery("#fb-code input").val("<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('fbpromo/settings/couponcode'); ?>");
    });     

    window.FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function (response) {
        jQuery("#fb-code input").val("Code will appear here");
    });
    };

    (function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    </script>
```

Somehow when I click on FB like button it will open the FB popup for confirmation for like the page. Once I liked the page, Button becomes liked but the coupon code div #fb-code input is not displaying. When I unlike and do like one more time coupon code div #fb-code input becomes visible.

So the bottom line is **edge.create** event not trigger on first like event. Any solution?

Comment: you do know that like gating and rewarding users in any way for liking is not allowed, right?

Comment: @luschn I have seen on many sites. I don't know it is allowed or not

Comment: you MUST read the platform policy before using the facebook api. just because you see it on another page does not mean it´s allowed.

Comment: @luschn Than you.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/examples-platform-policy-4.5

> Don’t incentivize people to like a Page, or give the impression that liking a Page will be rewarded. See examples above and below.

It is clearly forbidden to reward users for liking a Page.

The completely platform policy: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

---

Also:

> edge.create and edge.remove JS SDK Events: These Events will no longer be accessible. As an alternative, you can use our Webhooks and be notified every time someone likes one of your Facebook Pages.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/11/07/changes-developer-offerings/